# Not sure how to deal with Query String when submitting a form

Tags: php, jquery, html, query-string

If you go to this website: http://www.lodgeatjh.com, and you fill out the book online form and hit "Check Availability", I get the following query string:

```
http://www.secure-res.com/res/vn4/avail.aspx?hotelid=3687&checkindate=3/17/2012&nights=3&rooms=1&adults=1&children=0&childrenages=&trr=6FFFFFD8E9AC12&culture=1&culturename=en-US&wtpid=1
```

Now, I have to recreate this website with a custom theme and place it in wordpress. I do understand the query string changes values based on what a client decides to select. However, my string query does not match the one above.

Here is my form:

```
<form id="form" method="GET" target="_blank" action="/res/vn4/avail.aspx?">

            <input type="hidden" name="hotelid" value="3687" />

            <label id="checkin">Check-in Date:</label>
            <input type="text" name="checkindate" id="datepicker" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" size="10" />

           <!--<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/images/calendar.gif" border="0" width="22" height="19" alt="calendar" />-->
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <label id="nights">Nights:</label>
            <select name="nights" id="nights">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
                <option value="10">10</option>
                <option value="11">11</option>
                <option value="12">12</option>
                <option value="13">13</option>
                <option value="14">14</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
             <label id="rooms">Rooms:</label>
            <select name="rooms" id="rooms">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <label id="adults">Adults:</label>
            <select name="adults" id="adults">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <label id="children">Children:</label>
            <select name="children" id="children">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
                <option value="8">8</option>
                <option value="9">9</option>
            </select>
            <input type="hidden" name="childrenages" value="" />
            <input type="hidden" name="hotelid" value="3687" />
            <input type="hidden" name="trr" value="BFFFFFD8EA3772" />
            <input type="hidden" name="culture" value="1" />
            <input type="hidden" name="culturename" value="en-US" />
            <input type="hidden" name="wtpid" value="1" />
            &nbsp;
            &nbsp;
            <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Check Availability" />
        </form>
```

Questions:

1. When I upload this website to their server, in the action attribute do I put "/res/vn4/avail.aspx?" ?
2. In order for me to get the last part of the query string (children=0&childrenages=&trr=6FFFFFD8E9AC12&culture=1&culturename=en-US&wtpid=1), I need to use input fields with type="hidden" and set its values to whatever it needs to be, correct? Do I leave childrenages value to an empty string () since in the original query string(childrenages=&) has a value to nothing ?
3. When I test my form on my local computer and when I hit "Check Availablity", I do not get checkindate=3/17/2012 in my query string, but I get something like checkin=3%2F17%2F2012. Note that I'm using jquery datepicker for the checkin field. I do understand the %2F represent the foward-slashes, but do I leave it like that, or do I have to change it to forward-slashes? How do I change %2F to a forward-slash? I looked online and I couldn't find an answer. I tried using the PHP urldecode syntax, and it didn't work out so well. Perhaps, it is me I don't know how to use it.

Sorry if I ask all these questions! It is my first time dealing with a situation like this. I have never done anything like this, and I'm glad I came across it, so that I can learn more stuff.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `>>> unicodedata.name(u'\x20')`
`'SPACE'`

Comment: Sorry, I'm not understanding your comment

Comment: I know...I just couldn't remember the correct format for a slash. That's why I say "but I get something like checkin=3%2017%202012 or something like that".

Comment: I can understand your question but i want to know what are you trying to achieve by replacing `%20` with `space` ??

Comment: I'm not trying to do anything with %20 with space. Sorry, English is not my forte. When I insert a date(for example, today's date...03/17/2012)in my date field using the jquery datepicker, and when I hit "Check Availability" button, the page will be redirected to another page. When I looked at the url, I get a query that is different from the original query string. The original query string is checkindate=3/17/2012. Conversely, in my query string, my slashes are converted to something else. It is not %20 but it is something else that I can't remember. I wrote %20 to make an example.

Comment: Ok it is %2F for slashes. I get %2F instead of slashes in my query string. How do I get it to stay as slashes and not %2F?

Comment: You do not want slashes in the query string of the URL. See what you get in php for `$_GET['checkindate']` and if you see %2F in that value, then you can consider doing a `urldecode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q1. When I upload ...?

A1. Not quite. Leave off the '?'. You probably want a .php extension for your avail script not .aspx otherwise, with standard server settings, it will most likely not go through the php parser when served.

Q2. In order for me to get ...?

A2. Use hidden input fields for any fixed parameters which the avail script needs to have but which the user must not input or tinker with. The hidden fields values are typically written into the HTML by the script that generates the page in which the the form resides but in some cases may be dynamically inserted client-side (by javascript). For a null value, set `value=""` in the HTML. Make sure the avail.php script handles null and missing parameters appropriately.

Q3. When I test my form ...

A3. URL encoding is performed by the browser to prevent othersise illegal characters being included in the URL. Client-side looks after itself. Server-side, in PHP, the superglobals $_GET and $_REQUEST are already url-decoded. Don't urldecode() again or unexpected/dangerous results might arise (see the Warning [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)).

Another thing, you don't want `hotelid` in the form twice.

Comment: "You probably want a .php extension for your avail script not .aspx ..." No, you want whatever extension the remote URL is using. The remote script doesn't become PHP just because you want it to.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Read what I said again.

Comment: You need to read the question again. "avail" is a remote script.

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams Yes I'm fully aware it's a remote script. And I am advising that it should, in all likelihood, have a .php extension in order to ensure that it gets parsed by the php parser.

Comment: Why would a ASP.NET app need to be parsed by the PHP parser?

Comment: It wouldn't. That would be nonsense. In Q3, the OP says "I tried using the PHP urldecode syntax", which leads me to believe he is using PHP server-side, not ASP.NET.

Comment: Yes, *his* server, which is generating the form, is using PHP. The actual target of the form is *not*.

Comment: Then you and I have understood the question differently.

Comment: Thank you for your response Beetroot-Beetroot!!! Yes, I'm using PHP, but on their server, the result page has an ASP .Net extension(aspx). I'm not recreating that final page. So do I use avail.aspx or avail.php? My form needs to redirect to that avail.aspx page once a user clicks "Check Availability".

Comment: By the way, I actually forgot to take out the other hotelid. Thanks for bringing that to my attention

Comment: If the application is hybrid (php and asp.net) then each page must have the correct extension (typically .php or .aspx). However, hybrid applications are difficult to manage where user login is involved - reason being it's tricky because the two environments each have their own session. It is far more normal for an application to be written in wholly one scripting language or the other.

Comment: Clearly, php commands (such as `urldecode()`) won't work in an .aspx page. That's the point which stimulated my comment about php/asp.net and my spat with Ignacio.

Comment: Once again, thank you Beetroot-Beetroot. Now, I have encounter another issue that I wasn't aware of. When I look at the source code of the original page, there are no hidden fields except for hotelid. How is it possible that the rest of the query string(childrenages=&trr=6FFFFFD8E9AC12&culture=1&culturename=en-US&wtpid=1) are shown in the url without being hidden or in the form? Unless the code is written on the server, right? Also, I have noticed that trr= value keeps changing it values. How do I do that?

Comment: Agree, the extra querystring params must be injected server-side though it's hard to see why. As far as I can tell, they don't need to be in the url given that they are written into the form action attribute at stages 2 and 3. I guess that `trr` stands for "transaction reference" and can only imagine that it is used for tracking the search/select/reserve process and eventually as a database key if/when a booking is actually made. The 'trr' may well be generated by a third-party server - it's hard to tell without seeing the asp code. There may be a public api published somewhere.